# Downcasting pointer to member leads to undefined behavior

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, static-cast, pointer-to-member

I read somewhere that a pointer-to-member of a derived class can be converted to pointer-to-member of its base class. When I have read this, my smart mind started to think of many examples and keep inventing an infinite number of possibilities: do such casts lead to undefined behavior?.

[[expr.static.cast]/12](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#12):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv1 T” can be
> converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv2 T”,
> where D is a complete class type and B is a base class of D, if cv2 is
> the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. [..] **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.
>
> [Note 6: Although class B need not contain the original member, the dynamic type of the object with which indirection through the pointer to member is performed must contain the original member; see [expr.mptr.oper]. — end note].

**I want to know, are the following casts leads to UB or not** since they are not cast from "pointer-to-member" of `D` to "pointer-to-member" of `B`

```
struct B { int a; void f(); };
struct D1:B {};
struct D2:B {};

static_cast<int D1::*>(&B::a); // UB? (#1)
static_cast<int D2::*>(&B::a); // UB? (#2)
static_cast<void (D1::*)()>(&B::f); // UB? (#3)
static_cast<void (D2::*)()>(&B::f); // UB? (#4)

int B::*b1 = &D1::a;
int B::*b2 = &D2::a;
static_cast<int D1::*>(b1); // OK? (#5) -- fix of (#1)
static_cast<int D2::*>(b2); // OK? (#6) -- fix of (#2)

void (B::*f1)() = &D1::f;
void (B::*f2)() = &D2::f;
static_cast<void (D1::*)()>(f1); // OK? (#7) -- fix of (#3)
static_cast<void (D2::*)()>(f2); // OK? (#8) -- fix of (#4)

static_cast<int D2::*>(b1); // UB? (#9)
static_cast<int D1::*>(b2); // UB? (#10)
static_cast<void (D2::*)()>(f1); // UB? (#11)
static_cast<void (D1::*)()>(f2); // UB? (#12)
```

[[expr.mptr.oper]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mptr.oper#4):

> Given this member access expression E1.*E2, If the dynamic type of E1
> does not contain the member to which E2 refers, the behavior is
> undefined.

```
struct B { };
struct D : B { int b; void g(); };

B* b = new B;
(b->*static_cast<void(B::*)()>(&D::g))(); // UB? (#13)
b->*static_cast<int B::*>(&D::b);         // UB? (#14)

B *b = new D;
(static_cast<D*>(b)->*(&D::g))(); // OK? (#16) -- fix of (#13)
static_cast<D*>(b)->*(&D::b);     // OK? (#17) -- fix of (#14)
```

Comment: There's always a reason why a C++ compiler would report a diagnostic when attempting to perform a certain kind of a cast. Using `static_cast` to make the error go away does not necessary fix the underlying problem that resulted in that error in the first place.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There are no errors in the code I provide and can go away if I declare an object (in a block scope) to hold the result of the cast with `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute but there are maybe more UBs in my code and that's what I am asking for. That's I cannot know whether or not there's an UB in code by just looking to the warning.

Comment: @UnderMith I don't think it's UB. Isn't it correctly point to `D::a`?

Comment: btw what you quote is `D to B` and seems not what you're asking.

Comment: @user17732522 isn't it `&B::a`? not sure why compiler should block it imho.

Comment: @appleapple Oh, right. The type of `&D1::a` is already `int B::*`.

Comment: All of the casts in the first snippet seem to be from base to derived. The standard quote you are giving is about casts from derived to base. Sure you want to ask about the shown code?

Comment: @user17732522 - OK but there's "**Otherwise, the behavior is undefined**"

Comment: @user17732522 - Are the casts is UB?

Comment: @appleapple - yes the quote is from "pointer-to-member" of `D` to "pointer-to-member" of `B`. The standard says `Otherwise, the behavior is undefined` so if I cast "pointer-to-member" of `B` to "pointer-to-member" of `D`, Does they fall under `Otherwise, the behavior is undefined`?

Comment: Pointer-to-member goes the opposite way from what you might expect. A member of a derived class is not necessarily a member of its base class. So you can cast a pointer-to-member-of-derived into a pointer-to-member-of-base, but you can't use it without casting it back to its original type.

Comment: @UnderMith would you like to quote the full text? I'm not sure why you quote unrelated paragraph as if they're one.

Comment: @PeteBecker - *" but you can't use it without casting it back to its original type"* - If I am not cast it to its original type and then use it, what will happen? UB? `auto res = static_cast<int B::*>(&D1::a); B b; b.*res = 10;` then `b.a` will be 10, where's the problem now?

Comment: @UnderMith -- "undefined behavior" is not something that happens. It's a description: the language definition does not tell you what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

None of `#1` through `#12` in the first snippet are UB, since they are just casting a pointer-to-member from base class to derived class. This is an implicit conversion and the explicit `static_cast` wouldn't even be required. The conversion is described in [conv.mem]. Your quote from the standard doesn't apply, since [expr.static.cast]/4 already covers implicit conversion sequences.

`#13` and `#14` are UB for the reason you quoted, because the `B` object you created is the most-derived object and it doesn't contain the referenced member.

`#16` and `#17` look ok. The `static_cast` will result in a pointer to a `D` object, since `b` points to a `B` object which is a base subobject of a `D` object.

Comment: Thanks bro, can you provide an example that falls under **"Otherwise, the behavior is undefined"**. For example `static_cast<int D2::*>(b1); ` and b1 is `&D1::a` so `D1` and `D2` are unrelated types, why this is not UB. Same for `#10  and #11 and #12`, the type-id of the static_cast is unrelated to its operand!!

Comment: @UnderMith `&D1::a` points to a member of `B`, not `D1`. An example where your quote applies would be `struct A { int a; }; struct B {}; struct C : A,B {};` and then `static_cast<int B::*>(static_cast<int C::*>(&A::a))`.

Comment: Does this means from `#1` to `#12` are implicit conversations, and the explicit `static_cast` wouldn't even be required, as you said?

Comment: @UnderMith Yes, if you wrote e.g. `int D2::*x = b1;` instead of `static_cast<int D2::*>(b1); ` it would also work the same.

Comment: .. so when I convert pointer-to-member-to-derived to pointer-to-member-to-base, where's static_cast is then required?

Comment: @UnderMith When you actually do that. `static_cast<int D2::*>(b1);` is casting pointer-to-member-of-base to pointer-to-member-of-derived, not the other way around.

Comment: This conversation is covered in [conv.mem]/2 which is implicit also. I mean when does static_cast is required?

Comment: @UnderMith [conv.mem]/2 covers the implicit conversion base-to-derived. [expr.static.cast]/12 covers the conversion derived-to-base which requires `static_cast`.

Comment: Something like `int B::*b1 = &D1::a;` requires static_cast? which is derived-to-base. I mean [expr.static.cast]/12 should apply here?

Comment: @UnderMith No, `D1::a` refers to the member `a` of `B`, so the type of `&D1::a` is already `int B::*`. No conversion (implicit or explicit) is required. If `a` was a member declared in `D1`, then it would require the `static_cast`.

Comment: Thanks so much - I had to carefully read [conv.mem] section before posting this question.

Comment: Bro I am read the quote, but can you clarify to me what [this sentence](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.mem#2.sentence-4) means "The result of the conversion refers to the same member as the pointer to member before the conversion took place, but it refers to the base class member as if it were a member of the derived class. **The result refers to the member in D's instance of B**".

Comment: I know that `B` is a subobject of `D`, not vice versa as I understand from the quote

Comment: @UnderMith I think that is out-of-scope of the question you asked. If you have a new question, post it as a new question.

Comment: "*because the B object you created is the most-derived object..*" The most derived object is `D` not `B`

Comment: @0x0 In `#13` and `#14` OP is creating an object with `new B`, so `B` is the most derived object.

Comment: [intro.object]/6: "*an object of a most derived class type is called a most derived object*". And in the OP the most derived class is `D` not `B`

Comment: @0x0 The sentence before that defines _most derived class_, which is `B` when applied to the object created by `new B`, because it creates a _complete object_ of type `B`.

Comment: That's `B b2 = B()` and `D d2 = D()`, both are most-derived objects?. I mean `b2` and `d2` are not created with new, so they not most-deriveds?

Comment: @0x0 Yes, the most-derived object of `b2` is `b2` itself, the most-derived object of `d2` is `d2`, but the most-derived object of the `B` base subobject of `d2` is `d2`, not the base subobject itself. That's the point of the term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243125/discussion-between-0x0-and-user17732522).