# Pointer-to-member standard conversion sequence

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, pointer-to-member

I used to always copy and paste my code in [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/) to see where's in my code a conversation is performed implicitly by the compiler. But pointer-to-member standard conversion is not shown on this site.

I am getting more confused when seeing the answer to this question: [Downcasting pointer to member leads to undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71547323/downcasting-pointer-to-member-leads-to-undefined-behavior). I think the question itself is asked wrongly since, per my knowledge, a pointer-to-member can be safely downcasted, per [[conv.mem]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv#mem-2); but it cannot be upcasted safely except [[expr.static.cast]/12](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#12) is applied. This question has the following code (*edited*):

```
struct B { int a; };
struct D1 : B {};
struct D2 : B { int b; };

void f() 
{
    int D1::*ptr = &B::a;  // #1
    int D1::*ptr = &D2::a; // #2
    int B::*ptr = &D1::a;  // #3
    int D1::*ptr = &D2::b; // #4
}
```

My confusion arises just because I don't know **to-what actually `ptr` is pointing? to the member of the enclosing object itself? or to the member of the subobject of the enclosing object?**

Hence, before posting any questions here, I am turned to a some C++ programmer (actually my retired teacher) to help me and explain the above implicit conversations (if any). And *briefly* that's what I am getting:

**#1-** Here, the initializer is a prvalue designating a pointer-to-member `B::a`. And because the `D1` has `B` unnamed subobject, `ptr` can point to the `a` member of that subobject; in fact, `ptr` points to `D1::B::a`, where `B::a` is a member of `B` subobject of `D1`. The resulting pointer `ptr` refers to the same member of the subobject `B` (not `D1`) which is actually `D1::B::a`; that's because even if `D1` has an actual not-inherited member named `a`, the resulting pointer still refers to the same member of that subobject.

**#2-** Here, the initializer is a prvalue designating a pointer-to-member `D2::a`. And because the `D2` (like `D1`) has `B` unnamed subobject, `ptr` can point to the `a` member of that subobject; in fact, `ptr` points to `D1::B::a`, where `B::a` is a member of `B` subobject of `D1`. The resulting pointer `ptr` refers to the same member of the subobject `B` (not `D1`) which is actually `D1::B::a` that's because even if `D1` has an actual not-inherited member named `a`, the resulting pointer still refers to the same member of that subobject.

**#3-** Here, the initializer is a prvalue designating a pointer-to-member `D1::a`. And because the `D1` has `B` unnamed subobject, `ptr` can point to the `a` member of that subobject; in fact, `ptr` points to `D1::B::a`, where `B::a` is a member of `B` subobject of `D1`. The resulting pointer `ptr` refers to the same member of the subobject `B` (not `D1`) which is actually `D1::B::a`; that's because even if `D1` has an actual not-inherited member named `a`, the resulting pointer still refers to the same member of that subobject.

**#4-** Here, the initializer is a prvalue designating a pointer-to-member `D2::b`. And because the `D2` has no `D1` subobject can `ptr` pointer points to its `D1::a` member, the program necessitates this conversion is ill-formed even if `static_cast` is used.

Actually, I feel that this explanation is logical and satisfies me, but I think that it has some mistakes and is not 100% true, specifically, paragraph **#3**.

**My Question:**

- Are the above explanations entirely true?

Please feel free to correct the paragraphs if they have some mistakes, and answer with the corrected paragraphs, if possible. Thanks, and sorry for taking long.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise thinking of a pointer to a member as an offset, not really a pointer at all.

So the pointer to member tells you what offset to use to get to a particular member within an object--but to dereference it, you have to combine the pointer to member with the base address of an object of the appropriate type.

That means a pointer to member, on its own, doesn't really point to anything. It (at least normally) specifies an adjustment/offset that can be applied to the address of an actual object to get to the specified member of that object.

Most of your first three questions really boil down to how name lookup is done. When you give the name of a member, the compiler looks up the name, and figures out what part of the object that name refers to. The pointer to member than holds whatever offset is necessary to get to that member of an instance of that object, or any object derived from that one (which gets tricky in one case (I'll get into below, but that you didn't ask about).

So, in your first three cases, in any of B, D1, or D2, there's only one member named `a`. So when the name `a` is looked up, it's going to refer to the `a` that's a member of the base class, regardless of how you designated it, and the pointer to member is going to hold the same offset.

Your fourth case simply shouldn't compile as it stands now. With a static cast, you can make it compile, but the only way to use it would be to cast it back to a `D2::*` (and then apply it to an object of type `D2` or something derived from it).

Above I mentioned an interesting case you didn't cover. That's when you get multiple inheritance involved. In this case, the compiler may need to apply two different offsets when you refer to a member of a base class object.

```cpp
struct B1 { int a; };
struct B2 { int b; };
struct D1 : public B1, public B2 {};

int B1::*ptr1 = &B1::a;
int B2::*ptr2 = &B2::b;

D1 d;
d.*ptr1 = 1;
d.*ptr2 = 2;
```

In this case, `ptr1` and `ptr2` each contain the offset of `a` and `b` in their respective classes (normally going to be 0 in both cases).

But when we apply then to an object of `D1` (which has both `B1` and `B2` base classes) the compiler has to first apply one offset to get to the base class sub-object, then apply the second pointer to member offset to get to the member of that base sub-object.

Comment: "_but the only way to use it would be to cast it back to a D2::*_": The way the standard words it it seems to be fine to apply such a member pointer directly to an expression of the base class type if the dynamic type of the expression contains the referenced member.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion arises from a misconception that `&B::a`, `&D2::a` and `&D1::a` are distinct.  In fact, they are *identical*; they are each prvalues of type `int B::*`, all designating `&B::a`.  They are precisely as identical as `1` is identical to `1x` and `01`, or as, given `inline namespace ns { int j; }`, `&ns::j` is identical to `&j`.

You can observe this by compiling a simple program:

```
template<auto> int g();
int f1() { return g<&B::a>(); } // calls int g<&B::a>() 
int f2() { return g<&D2::a>(); } // calls int g<&B::a>() 
int f3() { return g<&D1::a>(); } // calls int g<&B::a>()
```

The best way to understand a pointer to (data) member is as a *function* (in the foundational sense); a pointer of type `T M::*` (say) *maps* glvalues of type `M` to glvalues of type `T`.  In the simple case, where the designated data member is at a fixed offset within the class, a PTDM may be implemented as a byte offset (in the sense of `offsetof`), but in more complex cases (involving virtual inheritance) it may need to consult the vtable.

Now, why is `&B::a`, of type `int B::*`, *implicitly* convertible to `int D1::*`? The answer is that a pointer `D1*` is implicitly convertible to `B*` (by derived-to-base conversion, since `D1` has an unambiguous accessible base of type `B`), and pointers to data member are [*contravariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) with their class types.  In other words, given a *function* from glvalues of type `B` to glvalues of type `int`, we can always construct a function from glvalues of type `D1` to glvalues of type `int`, by prepending the derived-to-base conversion: `(D1 → B) ∘ (B → int)` ⇒ `D1 → int`.

So:

1. `int D1::*ptr = &B::a;` is OK by implicit conversion (from `int B::*` to `int D1::*`.
2. `int D1::*ptr = &D2::a;` is OK for the *exact same reason*, since `&D2::a` is just an obfuscated name for `&B::a`.
3. `int B::*ptr = &D1::a;` is OK because `&D1::a` is just an obfuscated name for `&B::a`.
4. `int D1::*ptr = &D2::b;` fails because `&D2::b` is genuinely of type `int D2::*`, not of type `int B::*`.

You could *force* #4 to compile by casting via `int B::*`; you can explicitly downcast a pointer to data member for the same reason you can explicitly upcast a pointer to class: you're telling the compiler to trust you, that this pointer to data member of the derived class is *actually* a converted pointer to data member of the base class.  Since the explicit upcast `static_cast<D2*>` on a pointer of type `B*` is allowed, the effect of applying the downcasted pointer to data member is that of upcasting an instance pointer from `B*` to `D2*` and then accessing `D2::b`.

That is, given `p1` of type `D1*`, `p1->*static_cast<int D1::*>(static_cast<int B::*>(&D2::b))` is equivalent to `static_cast<D2*>(static_cast<B*>(p))->*(&D2::b)`, i.e. to `static_cast<D2*>(static_cast<B*>(p))->b`, **and likewise has undefined behavior**.

Finally, why does the compiler decide that `&D1::a` should be of type `int B::*` and not `int D1::*`? This is the language doing you a favor; a pointer to data member of base class is *more powerful* than a pointer to data member of derived class, since it can be applied to *any* derived class (with accessible unambiguous base). The only situation where you would want to convert would be where you can access the base class and you want to give the pointer to someone who can't, i.e. private or protected inheritance.